# C Programming Arrays

Tags: arrays, c, switch-statement, output, printf

The desired output of the code is: `6.30  1.25  2  14.40  1`
There are some mistakes in the printf statements, but I can't find them.

The Code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SZ 5

int main(void)
{
    int arg1[SZ] = { 3, 4, 7, 2, 9 };
    double arg2[SZ] = { 2.1, 3.2, 5.3, 7.2, 8.1 };
    char operand[SZ] = { 'm', 'd', 'r', 'm', 'r' };
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
    {
        switch (operand[i])
        {
        case 'm':
            printf("%d  ", arg1[i] * arg2[i]);
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf("%d  ", arg2[i] / arg1[i]);
            break;
        case 'r':
            printf("%.2lf  ", arg1[i] % arg2[i]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }           
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've not explained a problem (*There are some mistakes in the printf*). What *mistakes*? What is the specific issue that you're having? You've shown the expected output, but not the output you're getting instead. Your question title adds no information whatsoever, either.

Comment: @KenWhite I have written that the desired output is 6.30  1.25  2  14.40  1. But the output is not as expected.

Comment: Okay, so what is the output?  We can't make bricks without straw.

Comment: And I asked  you to **provide the output that you're getting instead** so we would know what that *output that is not as expected* is, and you've still not provided it. It's a relevant detail missing from your post.

Comment: You should really learn about `format specifiers`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You should use `%f`, not `%d`, to print `double`.
- The divisor and dividend are swapped.
- `%` operator cannot be used with floating-point number in C.

This code produces the expected output:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SZ 5

int main(void)
{
    int arg1[SZ] = { 3, 4, 7, 2, 9 };
    double arg2[SZ] = { 2.1, 3.2, 5.3, 7.2, 8.1 };
    char operand[SZ] = { 'm', 'd', 'r', 'm', 'r' };
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < SZ; i++)
    {
        switch (operand[i])
        {
        case 'm':
            printf("%.2f  ", arg1[i] * arg2[i]);
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf("%.2f  ", arg1[i] / arg2[i]);
            break;
        case 'r':
            printf("%d  ", (int)arg1[i] % (int)arg2[i]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }           
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```